# Does trade affect Earth's rotation?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, momentum, earth, inertia

Every country is trading with other countries around the world, some more than others.  I was wondering if there would be any change to the Earth's rotation because of the imbalance of trade between countries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Huge buildings affect Earth's rotation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65883/)

Comment: Duplicate of [Do we have any effect on the rotation of he earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56245/). Also see [here](http://www.joshphysics.com/2013/03/10/nuclear-bombs-and-the-earths-rotation/) (written by @joshphysics)

Comment: btw, the international shipping containers have 2 types. 20 ft and 40 ft. The 20 ft ones weight 2400 kg empty and have a max weight of 30,480 kg.  The 40 ft ones weigh 3800 and have a max weight of 30,400 kg.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I do not know that there is any rule forbidding humorous answers, as
long as there is a good physical remark behind it. I am sorry that you
were not able to understand what I said, but it was actually the most
sensible answer on this topic. Hence I would appreciate to have my
post undeleted as soon as possible. If you do not like humor, please
just say so.

Comment: @Chris The closing of this question is unwarranted because it is the first
time it is being asked in a way that encompass phenomena that
might have an effect (at least much more effect than what was considered so
far). Indeed the most effective way to change the
inertial momentum of the planet is by moving mass between the equator
and the poles. The previous questions did not give opportunity for such
an answer. This one did. And that was the content, in humorous form,
of my answer deleted by a moderator. I do insist to have it undeleted.

Comment: @babou (2 comments up) Humor had nothing to do with it. As you know if you read the comment I left you, your post was deleted because it didn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: @David I do not see that my answer is less informative than the previous one. I am actually describing the most effective way to change the moment of inertia of the planet. (sorry for inertial momemtum in the previous comment, I am not a native speaker).

Comment: Thinking more about it, I realize that my answer used a humor that was
somewhat too obfuscated for a layman, and I do apologize to the author
of the question. I should have been more explicit in the end. But I
would have thought that it would not be a problem for physicists.  The
earth radius being more than 6000km, moving things between equator and
poles will be considerably more effective to change the moment of
inertia than any change in altitude, especially when close to a pole.
In Montreal, change in altitude counts for only 70% of the height.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Could you please tell me the reason why my answer is not
being undeleted. Is that more difficult than deleting it ? You have
known the actual content of my answer for one hour. Asking me to
be more explicit is not the same as removing a good answer altogether.
It is as much an answer as anything else as it identifies the kind of
trade imbalance that would be most susceptible of an effect, if any.
The melting of south pole ice may induce the most important effect of human
activity on earth rotation speed.
Thank you,

Comment: @babou The reason your answer is not being undeleted is that there is no reason to undelete it. As I've told you multiple times now, it did not appear to answer the question. As long as that remains the case, there will be no reason for me to undelete the answer.

Comment: I intended to edit it, and said so, else I would not have written all this. I did not realize you wanted the edit first. Maybe you should make that clear in the delete information. It is obvious to you who knows the system well, not to others.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I am told that user babou mentioned the impact of shipping between different latitudes, which addresses the question, is technically meaningful, and is something that had not been covered by other answers at the time it was written.  Since it is deleted, I have no way of verifying this myself.  To the extent that I can understand, it sounds like it was humorous *with* a physical understanding behind it.  Is there something we can do to make it visible, or am I lacking the full story?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I would really appreciate to have my answer undeleted. Thank you.

Comment: @AlanSE "I am told that user babou mentioned the impact of shipping between different latitudes" That's not the case. You can look at the revision history of the answer now to verify it.

Answer (score 4):

This question is impossible to answer comprehensively, but conceptually we might be able to offer some new insight.  Certain *aspects* of trade can affect rotation, but there are many human activities for which we have *no* expectation of impacting the Earth rotation.  I will try to enumerate some here.

1. **ships** should not affect the Earth's rotation.  A container ship starts buoyant in the water at rest and ends at rest.  It uses its prop to push against the water to move.  While its mass was transferred, water was transferred in the opposite direction.  With no net mass transfer, the kinematics of Earth can't be affected by rule.
2. trucks that move **back and fourth** won't have any net effect on rotation.  One could imagine that one truck traveling East is balanced by another traveling West.
3. net **movement of mass** at constant latitude has no first-order effect on the speed of rotation.  Due to manufacturing economics, we may have increased the weight of one continent somewhat relative to others from shipping bulk materials.  But this doesn't affect the rotation of Earth if they're delivered to the same elevation.  The rotation can only be affected while the materials are actively moving, and only if it's not a ship.

So if you're not talking about these, what are you talking about?  The activities that can have an effect (at all) on rotation are limited to a extremely marginal slice of global trade.  Mainly, you can only speak about:

- Temporary effects, from the net velocity of vehicles moving (the ISS should count)
- Altitude effects, moving materials up or down
- Latitude effects, moving materials to and from the poles will change the moment of inertia and affect rotation similar to altitude effects

As you do the calculations, you should quickly find that mankind's hydroelectric dams will dwarf any contribution from material movement through trade.  Then open-pit mining will probably contribute more than trade too.  Melting of Antarctic ice caps almost certainly will.  Even ocean and atmosphere expansion from global warming will probably have a larger effect than simple trade.  Very few of the resources that go into trade participate in activities that can affect Earth's rotation.

Comment: @babou I've not seen your answer.  I had not read the comments on the question until I got your comment in my inbox.  There is a meaningful discussion to be had.  Moving from the poles to the equator will produce the most meaningful moment change.  However, it also needs to be mentioned that hydroelectric dams don't *just* increase elevation, because they lower sea level, which acts equally at all latitudes.  Artificial reservoirs in tropical regions should have a similar per-mass effect as polar to equator shipping.

Comment: @babou I encourage you to bring this up on meta, or edit your answer and request un-deletion.  I would like to read it.

Comment: I apologize and withdraw what I said if that is the case. But the
timing of my comments above and of your editing suggested that. My answer
was edited more than 5 hours ago, when I finally understood that
editing was supposed to come first. They could have first asked for
it, rather than delete the question right away whithout explanation as
to editing policy. I do not need to be forced to improve what I
write. That was ungraceful too and the site is poorly documented as
usual. And they are more effective at deleting than undeleting.

Comment: Regarding tropical reservoirs, the effect is indeed similar to melting polar
ice, though only half as effective for the same mass of water. But the
main problem is that you will never get anywhere close to the same
mass. The polar ice is nearly 30 millions cubic kilometers of ice, i.e
about 2.5 $10^{16}$ tons. That is sizeable, even compared to earth itself
(within 5 orders of magnitude). I think the maximum effect of polar
ice melting is about a nanosecond a day for 50 millions
tons. Transporting goods between pole and equator is 50% more effective, as it is not spread on the planet surface.

Comment: @babou Without checking the numbers themselves, I totally agree with your assessments.  I think that would be helpful in an answer.  There is a constant push-and-pull regarding site management.  You can validly say that the question about buildings affecting rotation didn't address the crux of the question here.  Maybe people weren't even thinking of that when they closed it?  Many question closures are subjective.  Specifically, I don't want users getting burnt by closings if they are using physics, and I think a lot of people on meta feel the same way.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider only trade imbalance, I would think that the trade imbalance between penguins (or white bears) and elephants will have by far the greater effect per unit of mass,
much more, for example, than the trade imbalance between yetis and whales.

What I actually mean is that the most effective way to modify the moment of inertia of the planet so as to change its rotation speed is by moving mass between the equator and the poles. That gives you  6,371 km of distance change between the mass and the axis of rotation. This is more than 1000 times what you can achieve feasibly by moving mass between a mine and a high altitude city.

Furthermore, altitude change is effective only when not to far from the equator, where it is effectively fully outward. In Montreal (latitude about 45) the change in altitude is only 70% effective ($\sqrt{2}/2$) because it is angled at 45 degrees with respect to the axis. And it is totally useless at the pole.

But I am not yet asserting there is anything measurable that actually happens as a direct consequence of trade imbalance.

However, human activity may have a significant effect on Earth rotation through the climate warming that may cause a massive melting of the ice at the south pole (Archimedes saw to it that the north pole would not matter, but Greenland may do its 10% bit). The water from the melt with spread over the oceans so that a good part of it will end up much further away from the planet axis, slowing the rotation of the planet.

Exact computation is not easy as it must take into account a lot of factors, including the shape of the oceans coastline. I just did a quick search on the Internet to see whether other people had reach that conclusion. One [site](http://forum.arctic-sea-ice.net/index.php?topic=215.0) has a back of the envelope calculation that gives a slowdown of 8 seconds per day, which they think accurate up to a factor of 2. I would not vouch for it, as my own envelope gives 0.6 seconds per day slowdowm, but I think they made a factor 10 mistake in assessing the mass of the ice (unless I did). Actually. this is quite considerable.  But we will have other things to worry about, since that much fresh (unsalted) water in the ocean may have some drastic effects on currents, hence on climate. It may also considerably harm the ecological balance of marine life. And what else ...

The effect on Earth rotation should be slowly compensated for a part as the Antarctic continent will surge upward when the ice is gone (it is sort of heavy), thus taking mass from the rest of the planet.  Possibly we may have some earthquakes to help us forget about oceanic problems, but it should be very slow.
Geophysicists and climatologists would know all that better than I, including whether the warming will actually melt the polar ice. But observational evidence is not too reassuring.

**Some figures, from a well sized envelope**

The back of envelope computation. The continental ice sheet at the
southpole is between 25 and 30 millions cubic kilometers, to which we
can add 2.6 millions for the Greeland ice sheet. Considering the
0.92kg/dm3 density of ice, this gives a very conservative estimate of
$25\ 10^{18}$kg, which we consider as sitting at the pole, thus not
contributing to the moment of inertia. When this ice melts, it is
spread as a sperical shell on the earth surface (actually only the
oceans), producing a moment of inertia $2/3\ mR^2$ where m is the ice
mass and R the Earth radius. The Earth mass is $M=6\ 10^{24}$kg,
producing a moment of inertia $2/5\ MR^2$ for a full sphere. So the
actual contribution of the melted ice to the moment of inertia is $5/3$
of the mass ratio, as if the mass off the earth were increased by $5/3$
of the ice mass, i.e. approximately $40\ 10^{18}$kg. The ratio of the
two masses is $6\ 10^{24}/4\ 19^{19} = 1.5\ 10^5$.  Applying the same
ratio to the duration of a day, i.e., 86400 seconds, we get
approximately 0.6 seconds, which is, up to much approximation and
hopefully no goofing, the increase of day duration.

Now another possibibility to attempt to slow the planet, suggested by 
@AlanSE, is to keep
large tropical reservoirs so that there is more water near the equator,
and less on the surface of the oceans. However, for a given mass $m$ of
water, the effect on the moment of inertia is $mR^2$ instead of $2/3\
mR^2$ for a spherical shell. Hence the gain is only $1/3\ mR^2$, as
opposed to $2/3\ mR^2$ for ice melted at the pole. It is only half as
effective.  But what is much worse is that there is no chance that the
mass involved will be anywhere near the mass of the polar ice.

If we look differently at the first result on ice melting, we se that
the effect can be read as a change of a bit more than 1 nanosecond a
day for 50 million tons of ice spread over the ocean. The effect is
50% more if it is kept at the equator, rather than spread on the
planet surface. Hence trade imbalance between elephants and penguins
can result in a variation of the duration of the day of about 1.5
nanoseconds for 50 millions tons of goods.

**On the accuracy of the result.**

The calculation contains lots of approximations. First the ice is not
really sitting at the pole (this changes the result for ice melting,
but not for elephant-penguin trade if penguins live at the pole). Also
the water does not spread uniformly on the surface.  But these are
probably minor approximations.  One easily overlooked approximation
concerns the radial density distribution of the planet (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRadialDensityPREM.jpg)). The inner
core is about twice as dense on a bit more than half the radius. That
means that the inner 1/8th of the plannet, close to the axis, contains
1/4 of the mass. Hence the formula for spherical moment of inertia is
not quite correct. Furthermore, though minor, Earth is an oblate
spheroid, which changes slightly the moment of inertia (0,3% effect).
This moment of inertia for the polar axis is actually $8.04\
10^{37}\ kgm^2$ according to [current estimates](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/MomentofInertiaEarth.html).

Let us correct this aspect of the calculation so as to have a better
feeling for the precision of our result.

The moment of intertia of the ice as a spherical shell is $2/3\ mR^2$,
i.e. $25\ 10^{18}\ \times\ 2/3\ \times\ 6,371^2\ 10^6\ kg m^2$, approximately
$25\ 10^{18}\ \times\ 2/3\ \times\ 40\ 10^{12}\ kg m^2$, or $2000/3\
10^{30}\ kg m^2$, finally giving: $6.7\ 10^{32}\ kg m^2$.

Compared to Earth, this gives a ratio of $1.2\ 10^5$ rather than $1.5\ 10^5$ in the
previous calculation, i.e. a 20% difference, giving then a slowdown of
0,72 second per day, for $25\ 10^{15}$ tons of melted ice.
Given that the effect is 50% more important when the mass is on the
equator rather than spread as a spherical shell, that gives approximately **an angular speed
change of 1 nanosecond per day for a displaced mass of 25 millions
tons between pole and equator** (trade imbalance between penguins and elephants).